# Why does my org say "Trial Expired" when I try to log in and how do I fix it?

Tags: trial, partner-portal, login-errors

We have an org we use to do demos. When preparing for a demo this morning we discovered that the org had "expired" and we couldn't log in. We were instructed to call support who, after a lengthy wait, said it was a billing issue and sent us to billing. Billing couldn't even find the org (they wanted an org ID - which I couldn't get because I couldn't log in) so they sent us back to tech support. Tech suport this time around said it was a trial Enterprise account and had expired and there really wasn't anything they could do if we didn't want to start paying for it. We thought it was a dev org, not a trial Enterprise org and were instructed to talk to our ISV rep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While we thought this was a dev org it was actually a Partner Portal org which expires after 1 year. We filed a case on the partner portal and a representative there extended the org for another year. We're still trying to find a more permanent solution so we don't have this issue again next year.

Comment: Are you able to create a Developer Edition (DE) org, export everything from your Partner Portal org (perhaps using [one of these methods](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/47/copying-metadata-and-code-from-one-production-org-to-another?rq=1) and carry on from there? Though I guess the relatively low limits on a DE org might be a problem...

Comment: That's what we're considering doing right now. The demo org doesn't get heavy use so I don't think the limits will be a problem.

Comment: How do you get a permanent org?