# Migrating the custom objects fields

Tags: apex, force.com-sites, sandbox, sales-cloud, developer-console

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Copying metadata and code from one Production org to another](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/47/copying-metadata-and-code-from-one-production-org-to-another)

Can anybody tell me how to  migrate the custom objects fields etc into a developer environment from sandbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to migrate fields (and I assume you're talking about field definitions, not the data itself), is using the Force.com IDE.

- Create a project for the sandbox
- Select the custom object and/or fields using the Add/Remove Metadata
  feature.
- Use the Deploy feature to deploy those fields to the
  developer enviornment.

You can also use the Migration Toolkit (Ant based), but it's more work.

Use the DataLoader to transfer any object data.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there any logging of when you do deploys with the IDE ? I personally think it is easier to use change sets for objects/fields with the added benefit of having the deployed change sets overview.

Comment: thanks, I have done the same as you suggested and it is working where the objects do not have lookup but for lookup objects it is throwing error. Is their any way to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could also create a package and deploy that to your developer org then you don't need to install eclipse if you don't have it already.

to create a package you go to

Setup - App Setup - Create - Packages - New - you give your package a name and then you can add components just like you would do with a change set.

after that you can choose to upload your package. And with the url you can download and install it in the environment of your choice.