# Force.com IDE - Deploy Entire Org. to New Org

Tags: force.com, ide, salesforce-id, metadata, package

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Copying metadata and code from one Production org to another](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/47/copying-metadata-and-code-from-one-production-org-to-another)

Quick Question.

I'm trying to deploy an entire org.'s metadata into a new one, specifically its sandbox, but that shouldn't matter.  When I deploy I am met with all types of errors, like this field does not exist.

Can anyone help with this?  Is there an order of operations I should take that would allow it deploy?

Should I alternatively use an "Unmanaged Package?"

Only catch there is there is a lot of Person Accounts which for some reason is not supported in packages. Could you provide a workaround?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First, do you have Person Accounts enabled in the new org? If not there will be fields missing that will break your deployment. Salesforce support must enable Person Accounts (see the [Implementation Guide](http://na14.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/salesforce_B2C_implementation_guide.pdf) for details.)

I've done a large deployment with the Migration Tool where I deployed custom fields, objects, page layouts, roles, profiles, and workflows all at once (we built a new org in a sandbox and then deployed it.) We then went back and built up reports, Apex and Visualforce second.

Comment: Oh, this is great.  No I don't believe that person accounts were enabled when I attempted.  I'll enable them and retry.

Comment: So can you provide an order of operations?  I'm seeing custom fields, objects, page layouts, roles, profiles, and workflows all at once AND THEN deploy Apex, Visualforce and reports?

Comment: You might be able to get them all at once, but that was my order of operations.