# How to Import Apex Classes?

Tags: apex

I created a APEX Class, and I wanted to give it to my customer. How Can I do that ?

Do I have to send source code ? or WSDL ?

I am confused how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what customer want to do with your class.
You can send it as source code.

But if customer dont know how deploy apex class, it will be better if you deploy your class to his organization from your Force.com IDE. In this way you will know does your customer have all nessesary dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous options for deploying code.  It really depends on your use case.  There is a great discussion of this on the Salesforce Stack Exchange.

Take a look at this [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/47/594) on Salesforce Stack Exchange for a lively discussion of how to deploy stuff.