# How to create customField in salesforce with partner wsdl?

Tags: partner-wsdl

How to create customField in salesforce with partner wsdl?
Example please

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to create a new custom field, or populate it on an existing record?

Comment: Do you know what the partner WSDL is for and what other API's there are ?

Comment: I need to create a new custom field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a similar discussion [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/34330/import-custom-fields-from-wsdl). I also think that you can't do it from WSDl, you have to use Metadata API.